# Implementing JWT For achieving User access control

Tags: node.js, jwt, loopbackjs

We are using [Loopback](http://loopback.io) , for writing our NodeJs APIs.

Now we are looking for kind of defining and then implementing the user access control system i.e we gonna have 10 sub types of admin users.

Each subtype can able to see some action i.e each subtype user gonna have access to some end points, which we gonna define manually.

Now to implement this we have got [JWT](http://jwt.io) , which seems to have exact which we want. It will store all roles and roles permission ( api endpoints ) in json format , which we gonna encode in jwt , and then get the generated access token, which we can decode later to check validity.

So , the flow should be:-

a) Any user logs in , check its role on server side , then create access token by encoding its permissions.

b) Next time when user sends this access token , decode it , on server side , get whats accessible for the user, and then forward him or give him error based on the permissions list and the current requested api endpoint.

So is it possible to check the permissions before actualy going to api endpoint. ( like checking it in `server.js` in Loopback )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you use an encrypted JWT, the JSON information in the JWT is accessible in the client. It is just base64-encoded. However you cannot trust the information in the JWT on the client since both the JWT and the JavaScript code can be altered. But it is there for GUI and other non security needs.